# Load Jenkins shared library from same branch as current pipeline source

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

### Background

I have complex build system which is working and uses shared library. Pipelines code is stored in same git repository as shared library. Both sources are on `master` branch.

### Problem

Now I do larger refactoring to improve build and test process. So I'm working on `feature` branch and I configured respective Jenkins job to test it.

Since I introduce changes also to shared library one thing is annoying: to import library I have to import this library this way:

```
@Library('my_library@feature') _
```

So to merge this changes to `master` I have to update code.

Is there a way to access branch (or other kind of reference) which current pipeline code was checkout?
So when I merge branches shared library follows to without altering code.

I was thinking something like this:

```
@Library("my_library@${PIPELINE_SOURCE_REF}") _
```

I search documentation and internet and didn't found anything like this.

Or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: You specify the shared library declaratively, so its branch must be known at pipeline "compile time". I think you probably already realize the solution here is to separate the pipeline code workflow from the shared library code workflow, but it would just be somewhat annoying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

If it is enough for you to use a parameter for the library branch, it is possible to do so, check out the [shared libraries documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)

You would need to change:

```
@Library('my_library@feature') _
```

to

```
library("my_library@${params['BRANCH']}")
```

This should load the global vars.

If you need to instantiate some class, it is possible to do something like:

```
def someClass = library("my_library@${params['BRANCH']}").com.mypackage.SomeClass.new(this)
```

It has some limitations mentioned in the docs, depends on how your library looks like

Comment: I do not want to introduce job parameter. Library should just follow of pipeline branch configured in job settings. I think I've found desired solution.

Comment: @MarekR, can you document here what "desired solution" you found?

Comment: @RandallT. I did, I've posted alternative answear.

Comment: @MarekR, oh, I saw "Didn't test it yet, but it seams reasonable" and didn't realize this is what you were referring to. Did you ever test it? I was only able to get ${env.GIT_BRANCH} to resolve inside the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

On some none public repository I've found something like this in front of the pipeline.

```
def pipelineBranch = scm.branches[0].name
library("someLibrary@${pipelineBranch}")
```

Didn't test it yet, but it seams reasonable. `scm.branches[0].name` should contain name of branch used to checkout pipeline code.

Comment: This works, on my first attempt I forgot to remove @ from @Library